# Advance select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'connections' with these fields:

```
entry_id
user_id
connector_id
cat_id
```

Lets put some rows

```
    | entry_id | user_id | connector_id |cat_id        |
    |:---------|---------|:------------:|:------------:|
    | 1        |       11|     33       | 1
    | 2        |       13|     11       | 2
    | 3        |        9|     11       | 4
    | 4        |       11|     33       | 6
    | 5        |       33|     11       | 11
    | 6        |        9|     11       | 8
```

**Pseudocode**
(using connection between id = 11 and oid = 9)

```
Select cat_id FROM connections c
if cat_id is between 1 and 5 
   where c.connector_id = id OR c.user_id = id
   AND  c.connector_id = oid OR c.user_id = oid
else if cat_id is greater than 5
   where oid = user_id and id = connector_id
```

**In english;**
If the cat_id is between 1 and 5, it should select cat_ids from where oid and id are both in connector_id or user_id, it doesn't matter which order as long as they are in one or the other, but if the cat_id is greater than 5, it should only select cat_ids where oid is the user_id and id is the connector_id.

Result (for connection between id = 11 and oid = 9)

```
    | cat_id     | 
    |:-----------|
    | 4          |        
    | 8          |
```

One more example:
Result (for connection between id = 33 and oid = 11 )

```
   | cat_id     | 
   |:-----------|
   | 1          |        
   | 6          |
```

Please ask if they're parts that are not clear.

Comment: seems complicated to me, what is `oid` by the way?

Comment: If this site is going to get a lot of traffic, it's likely better to figure out another structure for this data where you can efficiently use indexes. This is going to bomb on larger tables.

Comment: @Rubber Ducky: Both oid and id are userids.

Comment: and why again the result of *for connection between id = 11 and oid = 9* is `4 and 8`?

Comment: I'm 'asking'. I understood neither the pseudo code nor the English

Comment: Because for entry_id 3, cat_id is btw 1 and 5,and for entry_id 6, cat_id is greater than 5.

Comment: Fair enough @Strawberry

Comment: @ColinMorelli: Yh, i'm thinking about that.

Comment: Also your pseudo code is not helping, you need to change it

Comment: Fair enough, I was trying to make it more sqlish :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by just following your if statements logically. Something like:

```
Select cat_id FROM connections c
where 
(id between 1 and 5 AND (c.connector_id = id OR c.user_id = id)
   AND  (c.connector_id = oid OR c.user_id = oid)) 
OR id > 5 AND (oid = user_id and id = connector_id)
```

Note: in agreement with some of the comments - ensure this is what you need to be doing. I made some assumptions about how you intended your logic to be from the pseudo-code, these may be wrong - so please think about it before just copying and pasting. This specifically applies to how you structured your OR / AND in the where clause.

Comment: You @Matthew are a beaut. That's excatly what i wanted to know. Yh i agree as well, they're about 10 other tables relying on indexes from this, i'd have to think long and hard about how to restructure it without it affecting the others. Thanks again :)